# Hosting local maven repository on Local Area Network

Tags: maven, apache2, repository

I am using maven 3.0.5 and I want the local repository to be accessed using the following url 
http://local.me/localrepo/

I have an Apache web server running which already hosts an svn and I can access the svn projects using http://local.me/projects

Where I have mapped local.me to 127.0.0.1 in my hosts file.

I was wondering if I can get my maven repository online as well.

Please suggest some solution for the same.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately just an apache web server does not seem to be sufficient to make your repository read/WRITE available over HTTP.  You need additional software, a "repository manager".   There is a list of them here: http://maven.apache.org/repository-management.html

You can make a repository on the local network available over SSH.  Here is how to do that.
(1) In the build section of your pom:

```
    <!-- Make SSH wagon available.-->
    <extensions>
        <extension>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.wagon</groupId>
            <artifactId>wagon-ssh-external</artifactId>
        </extension>
    </extensions>
```

(2) In your ${USER_HOME}/.m2/settings.xml (or wherever you configure repository URLs):

```
        <repositories>
            <repository>
                <id>my-repository</id>
                <url>scpexe://local.me/path/to/repository</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                    <checksumPolicy>fail</checksumPolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
        </repositories>
```

(3) In ${USER_HOME}/.m2/settings.xml, in the servers section, configure username/keys the ssh client will use:

```
    <server>
        <id>my-repository</id>
        <username>maven</username>
        <privateKey>/home/bob/.ssh/id_rsa</privateKey>
    </server>
```

This will create/use a repository (which looks like your local repository) at the path /path/to/repository on the server; it is not necessary to do anything on the server side other thank make sure this directory exists initially.

Comment: Thanks for showing the format of the repository URL - couldn't find it in the documentation. Only I don't get why you say a repository manager would be required. Apparently it isn't.

Comment: I believe you need a repository manager to serve (and update) repository objects over *HTTP*. The above shows how to do it over *SSH* without a repository manager.

Comment: This is not true. Any web server can serve a Maven repository over HTTP/HTTPS.

Comment: Gunnar: In that case please provide a link/reference.  Thanks.

Comment: A read/WRITE repository, serving artifacts and metadata and accepting artifact uploads, all over HTTP (locally OR remotely), *does* appear to require additional software.  As far as I can tell.

Comment: all you need is apache http with write access the file system. All 'management' is done by mvn client

Comment: @robotoaster by "apache http with write access the file system" did you mean apache has write access to the file system, or all maven clients have write access to the file system?  If the former, that is good to here.  So you point DocumentRoot to a .m2/repository/ directory, then what?  Obviously apache doesn't allow clients to write files by default. Any particular apache plugins required?  What does the apache config look like?  If you found docs for this setup might be helpful to post them for the benefit of others.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to setup any web server for serving a Maven repository. It really comes down to simply let the web server provide a directory on the local file system. There is no special logic involved for bare Maven repositories. All the Maven related meta-date is stored in files. The web server serves them from some directory on the web server.

Now, the tricky part is uploading content to it.

Disclaimer: I haven't tried myself yet. But ..

According to the [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-repositories.html), it may simply be possible to deploy to a maven repository using a `file:/` url and have the location served by a web server. There is also [another possible approach described here](http://stuartsierra.com/2009/09/08/run-your-own-maven-repository), which uses ftp for uploading/deploying content to such a Maven repository.

However, using a repository manager (such as Nexus or Archiva) makes it easier to also manage repositories.

Comment: The linked doc makes statements suggesting remote repos can be accessed via HTTP protocol but doesn't describe how to configure a bare HTTP server to do so.  I think many of the linked repository managers (Nexus, Archiva) *serve* the repo over HTTP, but that doesn't imply a bare Apache server itself can do so. Anyway I wasn't able to find how to do so when providing my extensive answer below which you appear to have downvoted.  If you can find such a description, please link it.  If not my answer is probably still useful to some people, and a vote up might help them find it.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Keith. I added more wording which should (hopefully) make it clearer. There is no special scripts or software required. All a web server needs to do is server a local directory containing the Maven repository. Content should be deployed to that local directory vie file:///... repository url if you have local access to the web server file system. Otherwise, protocols such as ssh or ftp can be used. But they require running special software on the server.